# Click в jq не правильно реагирует, но скорее я накосячил

Tags: jquery, события

В общем проблема состоит в том что при первой обработке события все проходит нормально, а при второй уже появляется неадекватность.

В общем задача состоит в том что при клике на поле появляется текст и будет на том месте до тех пор пока я не кликну вне определенного блока(в моем случаи вне черной линии что на примере).

Попробуйте кликнуть на поле ввода, затем кликните на блок который обведен черной линией, ничего не происходит так и задумано, теперь кликаем вне области которая обведена черной линией, текст пропадает это правильно тоже.

Теперь если повторить так подряд действия как я написал то при клике на поле текст появляется и сразу пропадает. А должно быть как и в первый раз.

Надеюсь подробно описал, так вот, как исправить проблему? и в чем собственно она заключается?

[**Код на JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TeF6n/)

Comment: @eicto все работает. Ответьте и я вам засчитаю ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вешаете события внутри hover по много раз, лучшим выходом наверное будет повесить события вне hover, с помощью on (в как старой live) и в hover переключать класс.

Если продолжать делать как вы делали, то вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $jq_send_me=$('.jq_send_me'),$js_me_img=$("#js_me_img");
    $(document).on('focus', ".jq_send_me.hovered textarea#send_me",

    function () {
        $js_me_img.css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).parents('.jq_send_me').length>0) return;
        $("#js_me_img").css({
            "display": "none"
        });

    });

    $jq_send_me.hover(
    function () {
        $jq_send_me.toggleClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

А вообще можно так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $jq_send_me = $('.jq_send_me'),
        $js_me_img = $("#js_me_img");

    $(".jq_send_me textarea#send_me").focus(

    function () {
        $js_me_img.css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).parents('.jq_send_me').length) return;
        $("#js_me_img").css({
            "display": "none"
        });

    });
});
```